# oracle join or union

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a condition where i get the users data from table A or table B wherever the data exists.
I cannot write a condition in java but it has to be done totally in oracle and result set sent to UI.
How can i do this in oracle sql.

Users table:

```
userId  firstName   LastName        MI
11          AAA         111         A1
12          BBB         222         B2
```

TableA

```
UserId  ROLE    firstName   LastName    MI  Grade
11      MANAGER AAA         111         A1  A1
```

TableB

```
UserId  ROLE    firstName   LastName    MI  Grade
12      LEAD    BBB         222         B2  A4
```

OutPut should be:

```
UserId FirstName    LastName    MI  ROLE    Grade
11      AAA         111         A1  MANAGER A1
12      BBB         222         B2  LEAD    A4


Select * from users u, tableA a, tableB b
where u.userId = a.userId
and u.userId = b.userId
and u.userId = :userId
```

Where `:userId` is the data passed from UI.
I have to get the data from tableA 1st and only when not found I have to get from tableB

Should I do a union or join which is more efficient?

Comment: Nearly 30 years ago the syntax for `JOIN` keywords was adopted as a standard *(ANSI-92)*.  ***Stop*** using `,` to implicitly join tables, it's outdated by Three Decades.

Comment: The data model makes no sense. Besides the two tables A and B, which should be a single table (perhaps with one more column if you need to distinguish between two "types" or "kinds" of information - the likely reason you have two tables), the first and last name and middle initial should only appear in the users table; why are they repeated in the other tables? How do you maintain data consistency? The two extra tables should only have the `userid` column, but not the other "general" information about users, such as their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `UNION ALL` on `tableA` and `tableB`, then do `JOIN` instead of `,`(`CROSS JOIN`)

```
SELECT u,*,t1.ROLE,t1.Grade
FROM (
    SELECT UserId ,ROLE ,Grade
    FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UserId ,ROLE,Grade
    FROM tableB
) t1 INNER JOIN users u
ON u.UserId = t1.UserId
```

Comment: thank you. One question what if I have data in both tableA and tableB? I will get 2 records right? How can I eliminate that?

Comment: You can try to use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` If you want to remove the duplicate data from tableA and tableB. `UNION` will only display one data row.  @JNPW

Comment: @JNPW - will the data in the two tables (for the same ID) be the same, or different? If it's different, how do you decide which data to keep and which to ignore?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `left join`:

```
select u.*,
       (case when a.userid is not null then 'MANAGER' else 'LEAD' end) as role,
       coalesce(a.grade, b.grade) as grade
from users u left join
     tablea a
     on a.userid = u.userid left join
     tableb b
     on b.userid = u.userid;
```